# How is the error from a promise being caught inside resolve()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

This is what my code looks like:

```
  userUpdate(req: Request, res: Response) {
    this.userTaskObj.userUpdate(req.params.id, req.body).then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'OK',
        message: 'User updated',
      });
    })
      .catch((err) => ErrorHandler.getErrorMessage('User', res, err));
  }

(below function is inside UserTask class)

  userUpdate(id: string, data: any) {
    let query: Promise<any>;
    if (data.provides) {
      query = User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$addToSet: {provides: data.provides}}).exec();
    } else {
      query = User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, data).exec();
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(query);
      // query.then(res => resolve(res))
      // .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

I thought I wouldn't able to catch errors from the query using resolve alone. But it does catch mongoose errors. When I replaced it with the commented part, that too works but the errors are caught inside the catch() which is rejected. How is the code catching errors without the catch() ?

Comment: Why do you wrap the query with another Promise? Try  return query instead of return new Promise...

Comment: That's a coding standard followed in my company. We do it for all "Task" class functions.

Comment: @anandsr-dev This makes absolutely zero sense and [is actually harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). A promise is not a "Task"!!!

Answer (score 0):

`.catch()` runs when the promise is rejected. An error results in rejecting the promise. As a consequence:

```js
(new Promise(()=>{throw Error()}).then(()=>{
  console.log("this will not display because the promise was rejected beforehand")
}))
.catch(()=>{
  console.log("this will run");
})
```

In your case, when the mangoose error occurs,   `this.userTaskObj.userUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)` has already returned, and the returned object is a promise instance.

This promise instance fails to resolve according to the query failure, so it is eventually rejected. Indeed, `Promise.resolve(Promise.reject())` results in a rejected promise [Note: as commented by others, this is anti-pattern].

Hence the .catch() takes over.

Comment: No, `resolve(Promise.reject())` is not an antipattern. `new Promise`, when not needed, is.